# Show that whether a holomorphic function has no zero in the left half space

Tags: complex-analysis

Fix a complex number $0<|\lambda|<1$. For $n\geq 1$, let $f(z)=(z-1)^{n}e^{z}+\lambda(z+1)^{n}$. Show that $f(z)$ has exactly $n$ simple zeros with $Re(z)>0$.

This is the original question that I want to solve. I find this question somehow ambiguous. Does it say

1. $f(z)$ has exactly $n$ zeros in the right half plane and these are simple zeros and and there are no zeros in the left half plane.

Or

2. $f(z)$ has exactly $n$ zeros in the right half plane and these are simple zeros and we don't need to show whether there are any zeros in the left half plane.

I can prove the second statement using the symmetric form of Rouché's theorem. But I can't prove there are no zeros in the left half plane. So my real question is:

Does $f(z)$ have any zeros in the left half plane?

Comment: $f$ has infinitely  many zeroes by general theory (entire functions with finitely many zeroes are $P(z)e^{g(z)}$ which leads to $g(z)=z+c$ etc)  , so in particular  1 cannot be true hence 2 is what the problem  asks

Comment: Thank you. That's the answer I want.